# problem combining slideshow and custom scrollbar script using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have two scripts using jquery 1) custom scrollbar content 2) fade in out slideshow. they both work individually well. but when i put them together on one page the  customscrollbar doesnt work. here are sample scripts 1) http://jsfiddle.net/3PaNV/  2) http://jsfiddle.net/BM3S3/1/   3) http://jsfiddle.net/MP6Lt/

Thanks for any suggestions or help in advance

Comment: Its So weird, i have to include jquery.js twice. one before slideshow script and (one after  slide show and before custom scroller ) javascript code. This worked but  I wonder is this the only solution for this conflict between these two scripts.

Comment: Lol . this made my other javascript code stop working on page. the typewriter effect + one more slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use jquery AND prototype.
You have to use JQuery.noConflict to solve this properly.
take a look: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: I have not used prototype. both scripts are dependent on jquery. thanks for reply

Comment: MooTools + Jquery cause conflict too. I suggest you to try noConflict.